# Advanced search in Rails App - MS SQL Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, railscasts

I'm getting an error trying to perform a search that was outlined in Railscasts #111 Advanced Search.

The code I have at the moment:

**Searches Controller**

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @search = Search.new
end

def create
    @search = Search.new(search_params)
end

def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
end

private

def search_params
  params.require(:search).permit(:firstname, :surname, :phonenumber, :department, :division, :address, :note)
end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<%= render @search.votsphonebookresults %>
```

search.rb

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
def votsphonebookresults
    @votsphonebookresults ||= find_votsphonebookresults
end

private

def find_votsphonebookresults

    votsphonebookresults = votsphonebookresults.where("firstname like ?", "%#{firstname}%") if firstname.present?
    votsphonebookresults = votsphonebookresults.where("surname like ?", "%#{surname}%") if surname.present?
    votsphonebookresults = votsphonebookresults.where("OfficeNumber like ?", "%#{OfficeNumber}%") if phonenumber.present?
    votsphonebookresults = votsphonebookresults.where("Department like ?", "%#{Department}%") if department.present?
    votsphonebookresults = votsphonebookresults.where("Division like ?", "%#{Division}%") if division.present?
    votsphonebookresults = votsphonebookresults.where("Address like ?", "%#{Address}%") if address.present?
    votsphonebookresults = votsphonebookresults.where("Note like ?", "%#{Note}%") if note.present?
    votsphonebookresults
end
end
```

I am getting a 'undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass' error when trying to perform the search. The search form is OK, but submitting creates an issue with 'where'

I am performing the search through to a database that is in MS SQL Server. I can display the entries in that database fine everywhere else on my app just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting this error because none of the attributes you check for are set when you first invoke `votsphonebookresults` on `@search`, so `find_votsphonebookresults` returns nil which gets memoized in `@votsphonebookresults`, when you then call `where` on `nil` you get a UndefinedMethod error.
More fundamentally, though, the problem with your code in the search class lies in the fact that you have an infinite loop, where `find_votsphonebookresults` calls `votsphonebookresults` which will in turn call `fund_votsphonebookresults`, so you'll get a stack overflow once the first issue is fixed.